# what is the use of nested containers and root privilege isolation

Tags: linux, docker, virtualization

I am doing study on docker container and got to know about container and operating system virtualisation. I checked wikipedia on comparison of OS virtualisation implementation. I couldn't understand what do they mean by root privilege isolation and also what would be the use of nested container ?

Thanks

Comment: Docker is no virtualisation, it is just process isolation. A docker container is a process, isolated, with a network card, 10 Gb of disk space (by default, you can change it). Yes you can nest docker container, see this example by Jérôme Petazzoni from Docker https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind

Comment: wikipedia says it is implementation of OS virtualisation. I know how to nest docker in docker but couldn't think of reason to do it ? What is the advantage of using docker inside docker container ?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://dantehranian.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/building-docker-images-within-docker-containers-via-jenkins/.)